# How to pick smallest number from randomly generated array in one function?

Tags: javascript

It my first post, i have some troubles with one javascript tutorial tasks. Yes i did research ;)
Task is:
1. Generate array with 10 random numbers.
2. Make a function where aray will be argument
3. Function should return smallest number from array

I did something that works but i dont know how to connect second part in one function. Thanks in advance!

```
var tab = []
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59 + 1);
  tab.push (random);
}

function getMinFromTab(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}

tab.sort(getMinFromTab);
getMinFromTab(tab);
console.log(tab[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function min(array) {
  let min
  for (const value of array) {
    if (min === undefined || value < min) min = value
  }
  return min
}
```